# How to have multiple child with their onTaps within GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have a sign-up page which contains Text like privacy policy, terms and etc and I want that on clicking those text webpage should get open.
I used the GestureDetector for that but the issue is that it contains one child only

But I want all the three texts to be there and should perform Onclick or here onTap.

Any idea?

```
          GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => launch(
                    'https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/UrlLauncher-        class.html'),
                child: Text('Terms of use,',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              )
```

expected: all three text with onTap inside GestureDetector.
actual: only one child is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a Row widget which contains the text you need, that is, privacy policy, terms and etc, as its children. And then wrap the Text widgets with GestureDetector widgets. A code snippet is given below:

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                print("Privacy policy");
              },
              child: Text("Privacy policy, "),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                print('Terms');
              },
              child: Text("Terms, "),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                print('Contact Us');
              },
              child: Text("Contact Us"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

### Outputs:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not directly supported by Flutter. But you can use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) for implementing the requirement.

It is similar to Spannable string in Android.